# issue :display shape android

Tags: android, imagebutton, shapes

I want to test my android application in a real device ,i tested first in a mobile with android version jelly bean 4.2.2 ,it worked well without any problem but when i tested with  another version(4.1.2) there was a problem :The transparent background of the images that i changed their shape has become black.

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

and here is the code of the shape xml file:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval"
    android:useLevel="false" >
</shape>
```

the code of the button:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/gps_locator" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified the background. It seems that black is default.

Change your shape.xml shape by adding the solid transparent background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```